# Simulation of Mavic2 pro isn't holding drone on air

Tags: python, webots

I've been trying to perform the simulation of Mavic2 pro on Webots using Python but during simulation the drone doesn't hold on air. I've tried "https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/tree/master/projects/robots/dji/mavic/controllers" but the quadrotor keeps moving from one coordinate to another with change in altitude also.

I've tried creating same logic provided in C or C++ cyberbotics controller but with python the drone doesn't hold on air. While creating the controller on C fails the compilation with unwanted reference error (have checked everything, the references are in place).

I just want the Mavic2 pro to lift up on air and stay stable. Please suggest if I'm missing something to make it work.

Comment: Please add in your post the Python code you developed that should match the [C controller](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/master/projects/robots/dji/mavic/controllers/mavic2pro/mavic2pro.c)

Comment: I am using https://github.com/Pallavi-Sharma12/DJI_Controller/blob/main/dji.py code to implement the simulation process similar to C as provided by Cyberbotics. I want the default mavi2 pro to start and move to a certain altitude (pre-defined) and hold at that altitude without changing it's other coordinates. Please suggest if I'm missing something.